# only get numberic value in qlikview

Tags: numeric, qlikview

i have this kind of data

```
-
B-3-I11
B-3-I12
BI1-I190
BI1-I191
BI1-I192L
BI1-I194A
BI1-I195L
BI1-I198R
BI1-I199L
BI1-I200Ac
BI1-I201L
conasde
Installation
Madqw
Medsfg
Woasd
```

this is the data I have .. now I want only those which start from B and have some numeric character in data..how I get in qlikview script

how to extract only those data ..

Answer (score 0):

To filter to those that start with B you'd do

`where left(Field,1)=B`

Then to filter on those with numbers, you could add

`and len(keepchar(Field,'1234567890'))>0`

So that would give something like this:

```
LOAD Field 
From Table 
Where left(Field,1)=B 
AND len(keepchar(Field,'1234567890'))>0
```

(where Field is the name of the field your data is in and Table is the name of the table your data is in)

Or, if you want to keep all the data but create a new field you would do:

```
LOAD 
    Field,
    if(left(Field,1)=B AND len(keepchar(Field,'1234567890'))>0`,Field) as FieldFiltered
From Table
```

Comment: i want condition after load .. like load task ID, Name,.....from table1 .. i don't want after where... and i want values which start from B and have numeric characters..i both want in 1 condition @x3ja

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You'd do:
`LOAD Field
From Table
Where left(Field,1)=B
AND len(keepchar(Field,'1234567890'))>0
`
Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: i mean i dont want these condition in where clause.. i want both condition in 1 line and then want to create as a field.. like .. load  name, id , (and here I want to use condition and create as a field ) as N_ID  from table1... i hope you understand

Comment: and i mean the data which i post is data in field which name is NameID.. and I want to transform the data and wanted to create new field as N_ID @x3ja

Comment: when i try this left(Field,1)=B this shows an error Filed B is not found @x3ja

Comment: I have updated the answer with some more examples and explanations